# Convert tab-separated text into an XMLType using Oracel PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, xmltype

In my PL/SQL code, I generate the following text which I write into the text
field (varchar2) of an Oracle table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT    'c1' ||CHR(9)|| 'c2' ||CHR(9)|| 'c3' ||CHR(9)|| 'c4' ||CHR(10)
       || 'A1' ||CHR(9)||  '5' ||CHR(9)|| '11' ||CHR(9)||  '7' ||CHR(10)
       || 'A2' ||CHR(9)||  '8' ||CHR(9)|| '91' ||CHR(9)||  '3'
FROM   DUAL;
```

The fields are tab-separated. I want to convert this using PL/SQL
into `XMLTYPE` which looks something like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<RESULTS>
  <ROW>
    <C1>A1</C1>
    <C2>5</C2>
    <C3>11</C3>
    <C4>7</C4>
  </ROW>
  <ROW>
    <C1>A2</C1>
    <C2>8</C2>
    <C3>91</C3>
    <C4>3</C4>
  </ROW>
</RESULTS>
```

I am sure there are many ways to do this, but what is the best way. Assume the above table will have < 100 rows and so space is not an issue.

Comment: I have edited the question to put the data as a DDL (`CREATE TABLE`) statement rather than as an image. Please review the edit to make sure that the data is correct as your image and following sentence was ambiguous as to how exactly the tab-separated field(s) are stored. If that is not how your data is being stored then correct the DDL statement to show the correct data structure.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it:

```
DECLARE
   l_xml XMLTYPE;
BEGIN

   SELECT XMLROOT(
             XMLELEMENT( "RESULTS",
                XMLAGG(
                   XMLELEMENT( "ROW",
                      XMLFOREST( d.c1 AS "C1",
                                 d.c2 AS "C2",
                                 d.c3 AS "C3",
                                 d.c4 AS "C4"
                      )
                   )
                )
             ),
          VERSION '1.0" encoding="UTF-8'
          )
     INTO l_xml
     FROM ( SELECT *
              FROM ( SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.text, '[^'||chr(09)||']+', 1, 1) c1,
                            REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.text, '[^'||chr(09)||']+', 1, 2) c2,
                            REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.text, '[^'||chr(09)||']+', 1, 3) c3,
                            REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.text, '[^'||chr(09)||']+', 1, 4) c4
                       FROM ( SELECT TRIM(COLUMN_VALUE) AS text
                                FROM table_name,
                                     XMLTABLE(('"' || REPLACE(value, CHR(10), '","') || '"'))
                            ) t
                   )
             WHERE c1 != 'c1' ) d;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (l_xml.getclobval());
END;
/
```

The output then looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RESULTS>
  <ROW>
    <C1>A1</C1>
    <C2>5</C2>
    <C3>11</C3>
    <C4>7</C4>
  </ROW>
  <ROW>
    <C1>A2</C1>
    <C2>8</C2>
    <C3>91</C3>
    <C4>3</C4>
  </ROW>
</RESULTS>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the table and then dynamically find the column headers and re-aggregate as XML:

```sql
WITH sizes ( rid, value, idx, item, num_items, lines ) AS (
  SELECT ROWID,
         value,
         1,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '[^' || CHR(9) || CHR(10) || ']+', 1, 1 ),
         REGEXP_COUNT( value, '[^' || CHR(9) || CHR(10) || ']+' ),
         REGEXP_COUNT( value, CHR(10) ) + 1
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT rid,
         value,
         idx + 1,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '[^' || CHR(9) || CHR(10) || ']+', 1, idx + 1 ),
         num_items,
         lines
  FROM   sizes
  WHERE  idx < num_items
),
rows_and_columns ( rid, item, x, y ) AS (
  SELECT rid,
         item,
         MOD( idx - 1, num_items / lines ),
         FLOOR( (idx - 1) * lines / num_items )
  FROM   sizes
),
cols ( rid, item, x, y, column_name ) AS (
  SELECT rid,
         item,
         x,
         y,
         MAX( item ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY y )
                     OVER ( PARTITION BY rid, x )
  FROM   rows_and_columns
)
SELECT XMLROOT(
         XMLELEMENT(
           "RESULTS",
           XMLAGG( rw ORDER BY y )
         ),
         VERSION '1.0" encoding="UTF-8'
       ) AS xml
FROM   (
  SELECT rid,
         y,
         XMLELEMENT(
           "ROW",
           XMLAGG(
             XMLELEMENT( EVALNAME UPPER( column_name ), item )
             ORDER BY x
           )
         ) AS rw
  FROM   cols
  WHERE  y > 0 -- ignore header row
  GROUP BY rid, y
)
GROUP BY rid;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT    'c1' ||CHR(9)|| 'c2' ||CHR(9)|| 'c3' ||CHR(9)|| 'c4' ||CHR(10)
       || 'A1' ||CHR(9)||  '5' ||CHR(9)|| '11' ||CHR(9)||  '7' ||CHR(10)
       || 'A2' ||CHR(9)||  '8' ||CHR(9)|| '91' ||CHR(9)||  '3'
FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> XML
> ----------------------------------------
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <RESULTS>
>   <ROW>
>     <C1>A1</C1>
>     <C2>5</C2>
>     <C3>11</C3>
>     <C4>7</C4>
>   </ROW>
>   <ROW>
>     <C1>A2</C1>
>     <C2>8</C2>
>     <C3>91</C3>
>     <C4>3</C4>
>   </ROW>
> </RESULTS>
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=501dffcb3cc0b25cd16ec347e4de6636)*